# Rviz: STL marker has missing or transparent faces (prevent culling)

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, mesh, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm publishing an STL file using a Marker message, and while Rviz can load the mesh file correctly, some faces of the mesh are missing. It seems that the faces that as a negative normal are not displayed. In the following images, the mesh correctly visualized on MeshLab (gray) and in Rviz (green).

Is there a config or plugin that can be used to visualize all faces correctly in Rviz?

**Update**: it seems that this visualization method is called "culling", maybe there is a way to disable it? A temporary solution I came up was publishing two STL files with the normal's flipped to visualize the two sides of the mesh!

The STL file can be downloaded from: https://file.io/I5aP4G4eVtWi

**Bottom visualization**: The mesh seems fine.
[image: Bottom visualization]

**Side visualization**: some of the faces are not rendered.
[image: Side visualization]

**Top visualization**: most faces are not rendered.
[image: Top visualization]

This is the code I'm using to create the STL marker, nothing out of the ordinary:

```
visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
marker.header.frame_id = frame_id;
marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

marker.ns = "basic_shapes";
marker.id = 0;

marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::MESH_RESOURCE;
marker.mesh_resource = "file:// " + stl_filepath;

marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358575/rviz:-stl-marker-has-missing-or-transparent-faces-(prevent-culling)/) by [h3ct0r](https://answers.ros.org/users/27010/h3ct0r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ended up publishing 2 meshes: one with the normals flipped and other without the normals flipped. This way the mesh can be seen from any angle.

---

Originally posted by [h3ct0r](https://answers.ros.org/users/27010/h3ct0r/) with karma: 21 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0